# Create spherical camera app like google camera

Tags: android, camera, android-ndk, panoramas

I am trying to create spherical camera application using ndk to capture spherical image like Google camera. I tried so many github samples but some of them are showing errors related to jni files and some of them are slow processing.

Some of the Links i tried are:

- [CameraFocal](https://github.com/zmer007/CameraFocal)

So can any one please give me idea or suggest anything to create spherical camera application OR at least give me idea to capture image like [Panorama 360 camera : FB Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vtcreator.android360) application.

Comment: have you find anything on this. I also want to achieve the same functionality.