# How to make photosphere camera like in Nexus/Pixel camera or StreetView app?

Tags: android

I'm trying to find out how to implement spherical mode for the camera app, especially I'm interested in part of placing dots on a sphere and displaying them on camera preview. For instance, these apps have such feature:

[Google Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera&hl=en)

[Street View](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.street) - click on the floating button

[Panorama 360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vtcreator.android360)

[Gallery 3D](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3YrVQurVbEGZmRqSk5SQnNoOTg/view) - old version of Gallery app

I was thinking about ARCore, but for sure it's not used in one of the mentioned apps, because these apps work on the devices that don't support ARCore ([supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices)).

I also found similar questions

[Create spherical camera app like google camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439762/create-spherical-camera-app-like-google-camera)

[How to implement Camera functionality with extra options (like Panorama)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205548/how-to-implement-camera-functionality-with-extra-options-like-panorama)

But they're old and lack of any clues.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You can go through chapter 4 of this [book on google books](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=tfOoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=Chapter%204.%20Panoramic%20Image%20Stitching%20Application%20Using%20Android%20Studio%20and%20NDK&source=bl&ots=5YYrY84zhD&sig=ACfU3U1SZpm5fdMI98zy3yq6qqTOzmwRvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiog9q4g6PiAhWBuY8KHcxoAcIQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ) and also check this [project](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-PanoramaDemo).
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the event handling using accelerometer of the android , you can capture the events like here How to detect shake event with android? , and then can possibly turn on your camera and perform your events.

Also try this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

You need to capture the multiple images and then combine them by using specific algorithm to have the Panoram 360 view on it.

The algorithm like Image stitching like this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching

Most Important Thing : No one is going to reveal their algorithm on any opensource forum (As per I know)

**Have a look at this too :** math explanations

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4670/2010fa/projects/final/results/group_of_acc269_ty244_yc563/cs4670_final.html